# How to configure desktop appearance from the terminal?

Tags: command-line, bash

I'm creating a small script to setup the installation with my preferences and I'd like to know how can I change desktop appearance settings from the terminal.

Things like:

- Set the default app to show videos
- Change touchpad preferences
- Add custom keyboard shortcuts
- Change the panel location
  ... and things like that?

I believe all this sort of configuration is stored in some files somewhere. Is there a way I can change this sort of thing from the terminal? Can you show me a resource where I can learn more about it?

Comment: You can access most of these via the `gsettings` command. Install `dconf-editor`, use it to browse around, then you can apply the changes in a script via `gsettings`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Most of these settings are stored in the **dconf** database.

I'd suggest to monitor the **dconf** change using the `donf watch /` command and change a desktop setting using the GUI.

So first open a terminal and start the **dconf** monitoring and open the system settings->Appearance menu :

[image]

On close, you can see the above settings stored in the database.

Now to set a value from your installation script you can use for example:

```
dconf write /org/compiz/profiles/unity/plugins/unityshell/icon-size 32
```

to set the launcher icon size.

Look at the [`dconf`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/en/man1/dconf.1.html) and [`gsettings`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/man1/gsettings.1.html) commands man pages, you can set most of your desktop settings by using this method.

Comment: And I learned something too today!  (Upvoted!)

Comment: @Fabby I remember some of your posts where you also teach someone how to fish ;)